# How to edit behaviour of frame titles during frame break in beamer?

Tags: beamer, titles, frame-title

When the `allowframebreaks` option is used, the frame title is automatically numbered in roman numerals.

```
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks=0.8]{Frame Title}
.
.
\end{frame}
```

Here is what I get for the two of the frame titles after breaking.

> Frame Title I
>
> .
>
> .
>
> Frame Title II
>
> .
>
> .

I would like to have something like 'contd.' after the second segment and onwards or even remove the numbering altogether and just have the same title for each broken frame segment. Is there a way to edit this behavior of frame titles?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}[from second][(contd.)]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks=0.8]{Frame Title}
    .

    \framebreak
    .
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for introducing the `[from second]` option!