# How to remove frame title starting from the second slide?

Tags: beamer, titles, frame-title

The following code which is found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295854/how-to-edit-behaviour-of-frame-titles-during-frame-break-in-beamer) change the auto-numbered frame title when we use `allowframebreaks` starting from the second slide, but I don't want the frame title starting from the second slide. So how can I delete them?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}[from second][(contd.)]



\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks=0.8]{Frame Title}
    .

    \framebreak
    .
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a test to the frametitle template, which tests if it's the first slide:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}{}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
\ifnum\insertcontinuationcount=1
  \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{frametitle}{}{\nointerlineskip}%
  \@tempdima=\textwidth%
  \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@leftmargin%
  \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@rightmargin%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.3cm,left,wd=\the\@tempdima]{frametitle}
    \usebeamerfont{frametitle}%
    \vbox{}\vskip-1ex%
    \if@tempswa\else\csname beamer@fteleft\endcsname\fi%
    \strut\insertframetitle\strut\par%
    {%
      \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
      {\usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle\strut\par}%
      \fi
    }%
    \vskip-1ex%
    \if@tempswa\else\vskip-.3cm\fi% set inside beamercolorbox... evil here...
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks=0.8]{Frame Title}
    .

    \framebreak
    .
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```